# lengths of lists are not same when appending items

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a web-scraping project, in which I have to search for a product in a website and append all details of the product to respective lists.

for example, the first page of this [URL](https://www.barcodelookup.com/close-up) lists 10 products with the name "CLOSE UP". I have to append the title of the product to a list, barcode of the product to another list and so on..

I have to do this for multiple pages as well.

This is my code so far

```
def find_items(base_url, item_to_find, num_of_pages):
    
    title_list = []
    barcode_list = []
    category_list = []
    manufacturer_list = []
    
    url = base_url + item_to_find + '/'
    
    for num in range(1, num_of_pages+1):
        url = url + str(num)
        print(url)
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        a_tags = soup.find_all('a', {"class": 'product-search-item'})
        
        for tag in a_tags:
            p_tags = tag.find_all('p')
            try:
                title_list.append(p_tags[0].contents[0])
                barcode_list.append(p_tags[1].contents[0])
                category_list.append(p_tags[2].contents[0])
                manufacturer_list.append(p_tags[3].contents[0])
            except Exception as e:
                title_list.append('NaN')
                barcode_list.append('NaN')
                category_list.append('NaN')
                manufacturer_list.append('NaN')
                    
        
        
        url = base_url + item_to_find + '/'
        
    return (title_list, barcode_list, category_list, manufacturer_list)
```

In the above code I use a **try except** condition to append the info to the lists as not all products have all the information. If the info is available append to list else append 'NaN'. that is what the code should do. This ensures that the length of the lists remain the same throughout.

But when I run the following code, the length of the lists are not the same.

```
title_list, barcode_list, category_list, manufacturer_list = find_items("https://www.barcodelookup.com/", 'close-up', 20)
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your try-except if one of the appends fails you append NaN to each one of them. Change your code with this.

```
for tag in a_tags:
    p_tags = tag.find_all('p')
    try:
        title_list.append(p_tags[0].contents[0])
    except Exception as e:
        title_list.append('NaN')
    try:
        barcode_list.append(p_tags[1].contents[0])
    except Exception as e:
        barcode_list.append('NaN')
    try:
        category_list.append(p_tags[2].contents[0])
    eexcept Exception as e:
        category_list.append('NaN')
    try:
        manufacturer_list.append(p_tags[3].contents[0])
    except Exception as e:
        manufacturer_list.append('NaN')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I understand now, what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

maybe whats happening is your try: is failing at some point and you are appending more items in except:

```
try:
    title_list.append(p_tags[0].contents[0])
except Exception as e:
    title_list.append('NaN')
try:
    barcode_list.append(p_tags[1].contents[0])
except:
    barcode_list.append('NaN')
try:
    category_list.append(p_tags[2].contents[0])
except:
    category_list.append('NaN')
try:
    manufacturer_list.append(p_tags[3].contents[0])  
except:
    manufacturer_list.append('NaN')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with you `try-except` logic. Let us assume `p_tags[3]` doesn't exist. You have already appended `p_tags[0].contents[0]`, `p_tags[1].contents[0]`, `p_tags[2].contents[0]` and then you get an exception that list index is out of range. In the `except` clause you are appending `NaN` to all four lists again. Note that you have appended the actual value and `NaN` for `title_list`, `barcode_list`, `category_list`.

The fix depends on what you want. A reasonable choice would be to append `NaN` only if you are unable to access that particular value.

```
def find_items(base_url, item_to_find, num_of_pages):

    title_list = []
    barcode_list = []
    category_list = []
    manufacturer_list = []

    a_tag_count = 0

    url = base_url + item_to_find + '/'

    for num in range(1, num_of_pages+1):
        url = url + str(num)
        print(url)
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        a_tags = soup.find_all('a', {"class": 'product-search-item'})
        a_tag_count += len(a_tags)
        for tag in a_tags:
            p_tags = tag.find_all('p')
            safe_append(title_list, 0, p_tags)
            safe_append(barcode_list, 1, p_tags)
            safe_append(category_list, 2, p_tags)
            safe_append(manufacturer_list, 3, p_tags)

        url = base_url + item_to_find + '/'

    return (title_list, barcode_list, category_list, manufacturer_list)


def safe_append(list_to_append, tag_index, p_tags, default_to='NaN'):
    try:
        list_to_append.append(p_tags[tag_index].contents[0])
    except:
        list_to_append.append(default_to)

    return list_to_append
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the problem now